# Query for display two rows in a column

Tags: database

can any one help in this? I have a scenario, after query to DB i will get two rows and it will be always two rows or more than that, but my UI demands to be shown in one row. how can v achieve this ???? here is one example

DB structure and the data is being showed in following format

Year | value 1 | value 2

2009 |  2000   |  3000

2010 |  4000   | 5000

My UI Demands the following.

Year : 2009 | 2010

```
  value 1 | value 1 
  value 2 | value 2
```

I did a search and got info it can be achieved using TRANSPOSE rows to column. But i am not getting how to proceed on the same

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do normal query (i.e. without TRANSPOSE) and process rows in business logic of your application. Achieving this using SQL is a bad idea

Comment: Yes we can achieve  it using processing rows in bussiness logic. But my requirement also involves pagination(showing the resultset no. of records),which i am not able to achive  using business logic.

Comment: @chinpavan: so you pass recordset directly to your pagination component? what language\framework do you use? is it web app?

Comment: yeah its an web application, using java language,for processi using buss. logic,i wil get two record set aftr my logic my record set doesnt exist itself.(cos i ve processed it and put in some other datastruc to display).SO for my pagination component i will not be knowing which recordset size to take and my rows may contain more than two or three colum.

Comment: still can't understand why can't you code it in java. could you edit your question and put your java-code to clarify it?